# Push to Github Fails under Windows

Tags: git, github, ssh

I was unable to push to github from the windows (DOS) command prompt but from bash it worked.

If I ran `git push origin master` I got:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I ran `ssh-add` I got:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Everything worked fine under bash (msysgit) - how could this be?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to realise that ssh (under windows) was looking for files called `id_rsa` in my `%USEPROFILE%\.ssh` folder but the files there were names `github_rsa`.

Solution:

```
rename %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\github_rsa id_rsa
rename %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\github_rsa.pub id_rsa.pub
```

Hey presto, pushing and pulling now works without entering bash!

Possible explanation: a previous install of github for windows generated the `github_rsa` files.

Weirdly, after the rename `git push` still works under bash!